# Invalid Crypto key with connected app

Tags: apex, visualforce, salesforce1-app, certification

I am facing system exception “invalid crypto key”.

I created a self-signed certificate using the commands listed below and ensured the certificate follows the RSA’s PKCS #8 syntax standard:

```
openssl req -new -x509 -days 999 -keyout ca-key.pem -out ca-crt.pem 
openssl genrsa -out sage_x3_int-key.pem 1024 
openssl req -new -key sage_x3_int-key.pem -out sage_x3_int-csr.pem 
openssl x509 -req -days 999 -in sage_x3_int-csr.pem -CA ca-crt.pem -CAkey ca-key.pem -CAcreateserial -out sage_x3_int-crt.pem 
openssl pkcs8 -topk8 -nocrypt -in sage_x3_int-key.pem -outform PEM > sage_x3_int.key
```

I encrypted the key and uploaded it as a static resource into our Salesforce org.

In apex, I am able to retrieve the key and decrypt successfully, but when I attempt to create the signed signature, for the JWT, using the key I receive the “invalid crypto key” exception.

I am using [`Crypto.sign(algorithmName, input, privateKey)`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_classes_restful_crypto.htm) to create the signature.

Comment: Hi ,i am facing the exact same challenge , were you able to resolve this ??